# Setting the fill color attribute from css in Ionic 6

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

```
<div class="button-bar">
      <ion-button size='small' [fill]="tabSelected == 'details'? 'solid' : ''" (click)='selectTab("details")'>
        <ion-icon size='small' name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>

      <ion-button size='small' [fill]="tabSelected == 'customer' ? 'solid' : ''" (click)='selectTab("customer")'>
        <ion-icon size='small' name="person-circle"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>

      <ion-button size='small' [fill]="tabSelected == 'colleagues' ? 'solid' :''" (click)='selectTab("colleagues")'>
        <ion-icon size='small' name="people-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </div>
```

When pressing a button I'd like to set the fill color of the button. In this case, I set the tabSelected on a certain value and then based on that make the fill "solid" or not.

I'd like to manage all colors from outside of the Html and thus set it through CSS.

```
ion-button {
  --color: var(--ion-color-pmblue-contrast);
  --background: var(--ion-color-pmblue);
}
```

This sets the background of the button to the blue, but in this case, I only want to have the active one have this state. I've thought about adding a class with ngclass, instead of for the fill, is that the way to go in this case?

Happening:
[image: with background and color set]

Preferred:
(this is with color set on the HTML as attribute color='pmblue') color on ion-button in CSS points to the text-color.

[image: with color attribute on html item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't ionc icon and button have color property?

E.g you could do:

```js
 <ion-button size='small' [fill]="tabSelected == 'details'? 'solid' : ''" (click)='selectTab("details")' [color]="tabSelected == 'colleagues'? 'pmblue' : ''" }">
```

Comment: You are correct. In this case I'd rather not hardcode it in the template. I did not know this worked. I can "define a custom color" for this specific element now tho.
The correct syntaxt is 
[color]="tabSelected == 'colleagues'? 'pmblue' : ''"

You mind adjusting it in yoru answer, ill accept it.

Comment: I corrected the syntax.